# Shopping Cart rule to apply fixed discount on different product

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add a shopping cart rule which gives the discount of 21 when there are specific five products in my cart. Eg: Five products with SKU S01, S02, S03, S04, S05, all having different product price. When added into cart total is 81 and Discount should be 21. The user should get these products in 60. is this possible? Thanks in advance

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. If you want to create rule, which apply only when specific five products are in cart, you have to add Shopping Cart Price Rule. When creating this rule, navigate to `Conditions` tab and add conditions for your products (for SKU -> first add `Product attribute combination`, and then under this condition, select `SKU` as attribute and provide appropriate SKU. Add five conditions and that's all, discount will be applied only if all of your conditions are met.

Comment: I have tried as you mentioned above but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible when you add the condition like as on screen.

Discount on different products:
[image: Discount on different products]